# Java Max/Min Program Keeps Returning incorrect Min Value

Tags: java, math

I'm supposed to get the smallest and largest number out of a sequence of numbers that the user inputs. The largest is being printed correctly, but I can't figure out why the smallest keeps being printed as 0? any help?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Look at the initialization of smallest.

Comment: how do you ever expect it to change value? It starts out as the smallest possible value, which you replace by 0, which is still probably smaller than all the values you enter. And, in addValue, why do you compare it twice?

Comment: Please, in future questions, put the actual code (formatted) in the question, not print-screens.

Comment: please post code as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: There are so many issues with the code that this has to be an april fools joke. You're taking the input from `scnr` outside of the for-cycle, so it only takes the input once. Your for-cycle is going to execute 3 times not 4 because you have `i<3` instead of `i<4`. Instead of taking the read value from scanner which is stored in `test` variable, you're reading the next value from scanner again in `myNumber.addValue(scnr.nextInt())`. You're initializing your `NumberList` with the no-args constructor so values are set to `0` and if you don't put in negativer numbers there's not going to be `<0`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `smallest` is initialized with value `0` in the constructor of `NumberList` class. Now, if you input a number greater than `0`, the `Math.min(smallest, number)` would always be `0`.

Also the `largest` will give the incorrect result if all the input values are negative.

So, you'd have to initialize the `smallest` with largest possible value and `largest` with smallest possible value in the constructor:

```
public NumberList() {
    ...    
    smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
}
```

or in the initialization block of the class:

```
class NumberList {
    ...
    private int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    private int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    ...
}
```

Edit:
Also, it'd be best to initialize `smallest` and `largest` in one place, otherwise makes the code hard to debug.

Comment: and don't change that value in the constructor